# bootstrap panel with angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to do angular ng-repeat with bootstrap panel using below code

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="user in users |filter:search| pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">{{user.firstname}}</div>

      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

It's working fine but its appearance  is vertical not side by side. How can I set these panels side by side?

Is there any way to achieve these features?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ngrepeat over col-sm-4. As of now each iteration makes new row.

Comment: yeah ,Thank you ,Its working fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat` over `.col-sm-4` as follows

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" 
       data-ng-repeat="user in users |filter:search| pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
     <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">{{user.firstname}}</div>
          <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap row works on 12 grid. But if a row has more than 12 grid it will wrap it new line..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users |filter:search| pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">{{user.firstname}}</div>

      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You missed the layout . Probably this might help you

Comment: I have tried this also but it wont help me whatever i am looking

Comment: any specific reason why it wont help you?

Comment: OP wants panel to stack horizontally...but with this approach, each iteration will generate a new row and consume 4 grids out of 12. Hope that helps...